# HttpListener class in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, http

I have found in this link how can we open a port to communicate with it with few tests (sensing messages) and seeing if it received well those ones sent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

I would like to open an URL

```
http://localhost:8080 (a port)
```

to test.

But it seems that it's only working on C#.

Do you have any idea if it's working on C++?

Comment: What's listening on that port?

Comment: @StoryTeller Before listening to the port, I would like to enable it first.

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"?

Comment: @AnotherTest it's ONLY working  on C# for the example shown

Comment: @MelMed, see ColinM's answer for why it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

For a portable library, you could use [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The link that you mentioned is for .NET Framework. Then you can use only with C# (or Dot Net languages)

You have this option for Microsoft projects:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/christophep/2017/07/01/write-your-own-rest-web-server-using-c-using-cpp-rest-sdk-casablanca/